# Setting HTML text using a loop

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint

I'm currently running a REST query against a SharePoint list and I'm trying to display the results with a $().text() script.  I have it working but would think there's a more efficient way.  I have many fields I need to set but they're sequentially numerical and just think there should be a better way.  Example below:

```
$('#div1Id').text(data.d.results[0].slot1);
$('#div2Id').text(data.d.results[0].slot2);
$('#div3Id').text(data.d.results[0].slot3);
```

Etc x20 fields...
I tried below, but I'm sure for reasons that are obvious to you all that know what you're doing this didn't work.  The "divId" loads fine but the dataId shows the text "data.d.results[0].slot1"/2/3/etc instead of the actual data.d.results:

```
for (i=1;i<21;i++){
var divId = "#div"+i+"Id";
var dataId = "data.d.results[0].slot"+i;
$('+divId+').text(dataId);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Try removing the double quotes from `"data.d.results[0].slot"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what your first example was doing, I think you want this:

```
for (i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    var divId = "#div" + i + "Id";

    // access the value from the "slot#" property of the object
    var data = data.d.results[0]['slot' + i];

    // get the correct div based on the id and then 
    // set its text to the value
    $(divId).text(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks mcgraphix!  Nailed it.  Just for my knowledge, is this functionally a good way to do this?  Better for example than having the 20 separate lines of $(div).text(data)?

Comment: It isn't a bad way to do it. There may be better ways but it is hard to say without knowing more about exactly what you're doing in the app.

Comment: Unfortunately the code is being built on a closed network, or I'd show a larger example, but as this is working we'll go with it for now.  I really appreciate the quick correct response though!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the `forEach` method, or as already mentioned, get rid of the quotes in "data.d.results[0].slot"

```js
var data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "Name": "Some Title 1",
  "number": "Number 1"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "Name": "Some Title 2",
  "number": "Number 2"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "Name": "Some Title 3",
  "number": "Number 3"
}];

//data.d.results[0] << you'd use this
data.forEach(elem => {
  document.getElementById("entries").innerHTML += elem.Name +"<br/>";
});
```

```html
<div id="entries"></div>
```